# Committing inside a South datamigration

Tags: python, django, django-south

How do you perform manual commits inside a South datamigration?

I've created a long-running South datamigration. By default, South appears to wrap the entire migration in a single transaction. However, since I'm modifying millions of rows, this will cause the database to consume all my system memory if I attempt to store all pending changes in a single transaction.

To prevent this, I'm trying to call Django's `commit()` every N records, but this throws the exception:

```
TransactionManagementError: This code isn't under transaction management
```

Even if I wrap the migration's `forwards()` method with `@commit_on_success` or call `[commit_manually()][1]` at the beginning of `forwards`, I still get the exception when I call `commit()` or South's own `db.commit_transaction()`.

How do I fix this?

Edit: If I wrap `forwards()` with `@commit_manually`, this fixes the error, however, `commit()` still doesn't appear to actually commit the changes.

My code looks like:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    @commit_manually
    def forwards(self, orm):
        mdl = orm['myapp.MyModel']
        q = mdl.filter(criteria=value_to_change).only('id')
        total = q.count()
        i = 0
        pending = []
        tmp_debug = settings.DEBUG
        settings.DEBUG = False
        try:
            for record in q.iterator():
                i += 1
                if i == 1 or not i % 10 or i == total:
                    print '\rProcessing %i of %i.' % (i, total),
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    mdl.objects.filter(id__in=pending).update(criteria=new_value)
                    pending = []

                    # These don't seem to do anything, as the changes above aren't visible.
                    #commit()
                    db.commit_transaction()
                pending.append(record.id)
        finally:
            settings.DEBUG = tmp_debug
```

My total is around 3 million. While it's running, I'll query from a SQL terminal, `select count(*) from myapp_mymodel where criteria=value_to_change` and the count shown never changes.

However, if I alter the above code to do `q = q[:100]` so it finishes almost immediately, my SQL query shows the change after the migration completes, implying my `commit()` does nothing and that the true `commit()` is only being run after `forwards()` completes. What's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve rows by chunks, start transaction manually and commit transaction after every a chunk which has been processed.

The main idea described here(tested!):

```
def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunksize=1000):
    pk = 0
    last_pk = queryset.order_by('-pk')[0].pk
    queryset = queryset.order_by('pk')
    while pk < last_pk:
        db.commit_transaction()  # Commit the first transaction
        db.start_transaction()  # Start the second, committed on completion
        for row in queryset.filter(pk__gt=pk)[:chunksize]:
            pk = row.pk
            yield row

qs = orm['myapp.MyModel'].filter(criteria=value_to_change).only('id')
for row in queryset_iterator(qs):
    row.criteria=new_value
    row.save()
```

Hope these help!

Comment: Like I said, commit_manually doesn't work inside a South migration.

Comment: I've just updated an example in in accordance with the documentation http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrationstructure.html#transactions

Comment: BTW in your example you should call `db.start_transaction()` exact after `db.commit_transaction()` and everything will be fine.